# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)\cdot\arctan(x)-x^2}{x^6}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Find $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan(x)\cdot\arctan(x)-x^2}{x^6}$

I've recently learnt about L'Hôpital's rule. When I apply it repeatedly here it seems to get complex fast, so wondered if there was a better way to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** $\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{15}x^5+o(x^5)$ and $\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+o(x^5).$

Comment: @Surb, the result of the limit is $\frac29$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now, thanks. Series multiplication (or addition etc) seems to be the way to go in some of these problems.